# Handsontable сохранить результат вычисления

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

Я хочу интегрировать handsontable на моем сайте, но, есть проблема , когда пытаюсь сохранить данные, расчитаные RuleJS (простое умножение), скрипт возвращает мне формулу типа **(=$A1*$B1)​​**, а не результат умножения. Как сохранить данные из таблицы, а не исходные данные?

Весь рабочий код на jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zetwin/qhjuuk5j/4/

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var people = [ 
                {base_price :'99', price:'13', unit:'=A1*B1'},
                {base_price :'89.99', price:'13.43', unit:'=A2*B2'}
                ],
example1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
settings1;

  settings1 = {
    data: people,
    formulas: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: [
    'Price', 'Currency', 'USD'],
    columns: [
      {data: 'base_price'},
      {data: 'price'},
      {data: 'unit'}
    ]
  };

  var hot = new Handsontable(example1, settings1);

$('.push').click(function () {
    data = hot.getData();
    console.log(data);
    //$('.result').text(data);
});

});
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, по-русски.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта `Handsontable` есть свойство `plugin.matrix.data` - это список ячеек, которые вычисляются в таблице по формулам. У каждой ячейки есть свойство `value` - это и есть отображаемый результат. Чтобы получить все данные придется воспользоваться функцией: [Handsontable.plugin.helper.cellValue](https://github.com/handsontable/ruleJS/blob/master/src/js/ruleJS.js#L1110) или [Handsontable.plugin.helper.cellRangeValue](https://github.com/handsontable/ruleJS/blob/master/src/js/ruleJS.js#L1172).

Например для вашего jsfiddle:

получение значения из правой-верхней ячейки:

```
data = hot.plugin.helper.cellValue('C1');
console.log(data);
```

> 48168.89000000001

получение значения всех ячеек (одним списком):

```
data = hot.plugin.helper.cellRangeValue('A1', 'C2'); 
console.log(data);
```

> Array[6]:
>   0: 625.57
>   1: 656.95
>   2: 77
>   3: 77
>   4: 48168.89000000001
>   5: 50585.15
>   length: 6

Мне кажется, что пока лучшего метода, чем `cellRangeValue` нет. Но на его основе можно написать что-нибудь более удобное. См. [Handsontable.plugin.helper.cellRangeValue](https://github.com/handsontable/ruleJS/blob/master/src/js/ruleJS.js#L1172)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как же я вам благодарен! Пошел разбираться дальше с передачей в пхп. Пока оставлю вопрос открытым, может кто-нибудь еще подскажет.